After updating Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise to version 17.10.1, I get the error "Frame not in module" when debugging SQL. How can I fix this?
I have recently updated my Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise to version 17.10.1. When debugging SQL from within VS, I encounter the error

Frame not in module (the current stack frame was not found in a loaded module. Source cannot be shown for this location).

How can I resolve this issue?
I tried restarting Visual Studio and reloading the project. I also ensured all necessary modules were loaded and checked for any updates or patches. Despite these efforts, the Frame not in module error persists. I was expecting the debugger to properly load the stack frame and display the source code for the current location.

I've yet to find any real value in debugging, especially given how much work is involved with getting (and keeping) it working. So I'll ask the same question I asked someone else the other day: Can you explain exactly what you're going to get from explicit debugging that you can't get from normal debugging of T-SQL (ex. PRINT)? See this video, for example.

Also see this Brent Ozar post.

What I did was In Visual Studio:

Went to Tools > SQL Server > New Query.
Connected to the instance.
Tried to run a procedure copied from the profiler using 'Execute with debugger':

DECLARE p5 VARCHAR(250);
SET p5 = '';
EXEC dbo.usp_Employee_CRUDOperations in_DMLType = 'S', ou_IntRetValue = p5 OUTPUT;
SELECT p5;

Previously it was working fine before update.
Note :  In above sql example '@' sign is missing on param and varaible

That doesn't answer my question at all? I asked "why are you debugging?" and you answered "I'm trying to debug by doing ..." Feels like a hole in the bucket scenario.

Why debug the procedure? That's a silly question—because it is quite long, and I want to see if I am getting the desired result or identify where the issue is persisting. For your information, debugging from Visual Studio is easier, and I have been testing this way for a long time.
When debugging, you can examine the code step by step without needing print statements or other aids, making the process much simpler.
The problem just arose, and now I am unable to debug this way. FYI I am looking for answers from someone who knows how to resolve this.

You can see this simple video  for reference

Should probably report the bug here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio i couldn't find any previous issues about it though

Microsoft broke SQL Server debugger with version 17.10.1 of VS 2022 try to rollback.
Everyone on our company is unable to debug.
